# Was there any significance for the make of the tomb which was used to lay the body of Jesus?

Tags: catholicism, exegesis, gospels, tomb-of-jesus

As per the Gospels of Matthew (27:60), Mark (15:46 ) and Luke (23:53) , the Body of Jesus, after his crucifixion was laid in a tomb 'hewn in the rock'. That all the evangelists except John mention the make of the tomb, suggests that there is some significance to it.  My question is: are there any official teachings from the side of Catholic Church on the significance of the make of the tomb viz. hewn in rock , in which Jesus was laid after his crucifixion ?

Comment: It had to be a very secure tomb and lack "escape routes" because the Jews did not want the Apostles to take Jesus's body and claim he was resurrected.

Answer (score 2):

I hope that this was written to indicate that Jesus had, in his burial, fulfilled the prophecy   of Isaiah at 53:9 (RSVCE)

" And they made his grave with the wicked
    and with a rich man in his death..."

Clearly, only a rich man could afford to construct a grave hewn in rock. And, Matthew 27:57 in deed depicts Joseph of Arimathe'a as a rich man !